# Converting a String to Type Object - Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have created a DataStore, and the type of fields in the data store has been saved in json format.
Something like

```
{"SchemaName": "Caztor", "FieldType": {"cain": "<type 'float'>"}}
```

Now when i load the json using json.load , the type of the field cain is being loaded as Unicode. Is there any pre defined methods available in python which can be used to typecast this String to Type object. Ofcourse I can make a function that would handle and solve the problem. But if there is already a solution to this in the python library then it would save a bit of overhead and might be more efficient in handling the problem than I might do.

Comment: How are you creating this JSON file? On both Python 2 and 3 types aren't JSON serializable.

Comment: Using the python json module and saving the dict of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution. JSON is a universal format across all languages and it doesn't make sense for it to be able to store Python classes. You need to define a fixed way to go back and forth between strings and types, which includes determining which types are acceptable. Here's an example:

```
class Example(object):
    pass

json_types = [int, float, str, Example]

string_to_type_dict = {t.__name__: t for t in json_types}

assert len(string_to_type_dict) == len(json_types)

def string_to_type(s):
    return string_to_type_dict[s]

def type_to_string(t):
    return t.__name__
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the module pickle to solve the typecast. this module can serialize the instances into a string
The Documentation is present on https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Example

```
import pickle
schema = {"SchemaName": "Caztor", "FieldType": {"cain": float}}
result = pickle.dumps(schema) # Will result a string
```

To deserialize use:

```
result2 = pickle.loads(result) # Will result a dictionary with typecast
```

Comment: This is actually probably a better answer than mine because the question implies that the data will only be written and read by Python in which case using JSON is pointless. My answer is only useful if a different language needs to parse the type. Using pickle will also be much easier for storing custom classes and so on.